# How to make a sidebar sticky and keep it below the navbar in bootstrap 4?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have a site that has a bootstrap 4 navbar on top, which has the class "sticky-top". It does not have a fixed height, as far as I know. Below that I have a container-fuid div and in it a sidebar on the left and a main div to the right. I would like to have that sidebar on the full height, meaning from the bottom of the navbar to the bottom of the page and at the same time I would like it to remain sticky, when I am scrolling down in the main window.

I have tried a lot with "position: sticky" and so on, but until now I did not find the right class or properties to get this working. Do you have advice for me?

**Update:**

Here is my current custom.css, but I am constantly changing this and trying a lot of different settings.

```
.wrapper { 
    display: flex; 
    width:100%; 
    align-items: flex-start; 
 /*   align-items: stretch;*/ 
} 
 
#sidebar { 
    min-width:250px; 
    max-width:250px; 
    background-color: #f8f9fa; 
    position:sticky; 
    bottom:3rem; 
    align-self:flex-start; 
}
```

And here comes the html excerpt:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light sticky-top">
   <a class="navbar-brand mr-0 mr-md-2">Tuesday</a>
   <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">    
   <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
       <ol class="breadcrumb">     
           <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="/Project/">Project</a></li>
           <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Overview</li>   
       </ol>
   </nav>
</nav>
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
   <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link" href="#">PLACEHOLDER</a>
   </li>
</ul>
</nav>
        
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="sidebar">
        <br>
        <div class="dropdown dd-custom">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle di-custom" data-toggle="dropdown">Bills</a>
             <div class="dropdown-menu">
                 <a class="dropdown-item di-custom" href="/Project/entry/">Enter bill details</a>
             </div>
        </div>

[and so on ...]

<div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main text-mainframe main-custom">

[here comes the main content]
```

Comment: Please post your code snippet, so that we can get to know what and how you are trying

Comment: Dear FeelRightz
I have added code snippets and hope this will help.

Comment: Try `position-fixed` instead of `sticky-top`

Comment: You mean for the navbar on top? And will this also help with the sidebar? I will give it a try.

Comment: Well, I tried, but it does not work. But I must explain. When I put position-fixed as class on the navbar then it stays on top (which is good), but it is kind of opaque and the rest (including the sidebar) will srcoll over it. When I put the same class on the sidebar it does not change anything with regard to not scrolling. And if I also put it on the wrapper div, then nothing is scrollable anymore, not even the main div with the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution that works for me and I want to share it with you. Perhaps someone else also wants to have a sidebar that sticks below the navbar and won't scroll with the main content in bootstrap 4.

I put an id on my navbar and made it sticky-top.

```
<nav id="complete_navbar" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light sticky-top">
```

Then I changed my containers including the sidebar.

```
 <div class="container-fluid" style="padding-left0;">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div id="sidebar" style="min-height:calc(100vh-document.getElementById('complete_navbar').clientHeight);">
                    <div style="position:fixed; margin-top:document.getElementById('complete_navbar').clientHeight;">
```

Above, as you can see, I added style="min-height:calc(100vh-document.getElementById('complete_navbar').clientHeight);" to the div with the id "sidebar". This is to calculate How much space (height) the navbar takes and make the sidebar as high as the viewport minus this height.
Then I added another div inside the sidebar. And this div is now being fixed and gets a margin that corresponds to the height of the navbar.

I am absolutely no skilled js coder, but I am glad that this works now as it drove me mad in the last past days and I hope it will help others in the future, too.